# how can I find a referenced Javascript method in a big website?

Tags: javascript, ide, browser

suppose I look at a webpage and I see something like:
MysteriousClass mc = new MysteriousClass();
mc.CallMysteriousMethod()

Now, the problem is that there are a zillion javascript files included into this page, and how am I supposed to find the one file that contains definition of this MysteriousClass? I know that this could be dealt with using a spider and grep and things like that, but is there a professional and elegant way to do this?

Clarification: yeah, so I would like to do it statically, without debugging. So Firebug is the right way to go?

As far as IDE go, which IDE should I use? Are there IDEs that will automatically download a website with all of its javascript dependencies and then allow static searches for methods and classes?

Comment: Is this really about JavaScript? MysteriousClass mc = new MysteriousClass(); does not strike me as JavaScript syntax...

Comment: @Jani If you initiate the object as a proper variable (no spaces) it is JavaScript! But you're right - that looks like something else.

Answer (score 5):

Firebug plugin of Firefox can help. Place a break point where mysterious method is called and follow the code flow.

Comment: firebug is very good at providing links to functions as well if you're in the DOM view, or even just ctrl+f

Answer (score 3):

What's unprofessional about grep?

```
grep -R "function CallMysteriousMethod" *
```

or similar.

Or maybe just use a modern IDE which will sort this all out for you.

Comment: Professionals use simple tools, pipes, and io redirection, dag-nab-it!